# Highcharts Custom Series Color Not working in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, angular9

I recently updated my application from angular 8 to angular 9. In angular 8 my charts were working properly and the charts were displaying like this. THe library i am using is highcharts.

Before updating to angular 9 my chart was looking like this.

[image: Chart in angular 8]

After updating to angular 9 my charts legend and color setting stopped working and chart started to look like this

[image: Chart in angular 9 without legend and color]

After going through differrent forumns i got to know that ivy is enabled by default in angular 9. We need to disable it in tsconfig.app.json. The legend displaying issue was fixed and legends started showing again.
The setting which i added in the file was this.

tsconfig.app.json
"angularCompilerOptions": { 
    "enableIvy": false,
     }

After disabling the ivy the chart started to look like this. 
[image: Chart in angular 9 with legend]

The problem is that the color setting which i set in my series is still not working. The code is mentioned below.

app.ts file
this.Series= [{ 
      color: '#0773D7', //blue color 
      name: 'Chart', 
      data: [30,10,30,10,40,20], 
      }]; 
this.Legend = ['Direct Financial Impact', 'Environment', 'Health & Safety', 'Legal', 'Production Loss', 'Reputation'];

Comment: Could you provide a live demo that recreates the problem? You can use this example as a starting point: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-pusuo?file=/src/app/app.component.ts
Also, do you use the official Highcharts wrapper for Angular (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular)?

Comment: @KamilKulig yes i am using the official highcharts library and i am using the  latest version 8.0.4, i am afraid i can't share the live demo as the application belongs to the corporate so that i won't be able to share the live demo

Comment: Could you create (from scratch) a simplified demo that doesn't use any confidential information (use random data instead)?